# How do you get systemd to reparse /etc/fstab auto mounts?

Tags: systemd, automount

If x-systemd.automount entries are modified in /etc/fstab, how do I get systemd to reparse the entries?

Answer (score 7):

I could not find clear documentation on how to get systemd to reparse /etc/fstab automounts without rebooting, so:

- `systemctl daemon-reload` will regenerate the units files in /run/systemd/generator but doesn't start new automounts or stop ones removed from fstab.
- `systemctl start newmount.automount` will start the mount. The .automount extension is required, as systemd assumes .service if not extension is specified.
- `systemctl stop oldmount.automount` will remove a mount not longer in fstab
- `systemctl reset-failed` will stop a previously failed removed mount from appearing in status messages.

Comment: If you are removing a mount that previously failed it will still show up in `systemctl --failed` and `systemctl status oldmount` (with a suspicious `Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)`). A `systemctl reset-failed` does the trick in this case.

Comment: @dreua, good info, added to answer.

Comment: Note that for adding a new mount point,  even after `systemctl daemon-reload` the `systemctl list-units` doesn't show the new mount point, but _attempting_ to run `systemctl start` on the unit (after path mangling /srv/example -> `srv-example.automount`) it picks up the new unit.
   
 -- 


Search engine keyword stuffing: systemd automount pick up changes, systemd automount refresh after updating /etc/fstab

Comment: I realize the unit was probably inactive and it would have showed in `systemctl list-units --type=automount --all`